# How do I combine the output of several MySQLdb fetch_all() calls into one list?

Tags: python

I have a loop processing the output of an MySQLdb queries:

```
for item in getItems()
    . . .
```

where getResults() is returning the output of a cursor.fetchall().

How can I modify getItems() so it combines the fetchall() returns of several different queries?  That is, once the results of the first query are exhausted, I want the loop to begin working on the results of a second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both queries have a similar column structure, you could consider using MySQL to combine the two SQL queries using the UNION keyword.

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table_x
UNION
SELECT d,e,f
FROM table_y
```

Otherwise, it may be easier to define getItems as a generator.

```
def getItems():
    cursor.execute(query1)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        yield row
    cursor.execute(query2)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        yield row

gen = getItems()

for item in gen:
    ...
```

Comment: The latter was what I was looking for -- some way for Python to just grab up and combine the results.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware about the details how you do queries, but something like this should work:

```
[item for query in queries for item in execute(query)]
```

where `execute` is assumed to return `cursor.fetchall()`.